# Assertion failed: !XMVector3Equal(UpDirection, XMVectorZero())

Tags: c++, directx-11

So i m basicly writting a camera class that is linked to an 3D object (that i have loaded into my programm as an .obj file).

The camera acts as a third person.

i get the error when i write this :

```
    World *= XMMatrixTranslation(XMVectorGetX(position), m_y, XMVectorGetZ(position)); //LAST MODIFICATION BEFORE BREAK
```

The original code was :

```
    World = XMMatrixScaling(m_xscale, m_yscale, m_zscale);
    World *= XMMatrixRotationX(XMConvertToRadians(m_xangle));
    World *= XMMatrixRotationY(XMConvertToRadians(m_yangle));
    World *= XMMatrixRotationZ(XMConvertToRadians(m_zangle));
    World *= XMMatrixTranslation(m_x, m_y, m_z); //LINE THAT GETS MODIFIED
```

Also :

```
XMVECTOR position = XMVector3TransformCoord(cam->GetCharPos(), World);
```

Where **cam->GetCharPos()** is a XMVECTOR(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) and World is a XMMATRIX that has a positon (that changes each time i move) of, let's say, (1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) // x, y and z position

So in theory, the position vector gets an XM vector of (1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)//And it does i debugged it.

Also i was wondering what causes this type of error in general? apart from what cause it to break my code here.Because i know they are at least 4 version of this error :

```
assert(!XMVector3Equal(EyeDirection, XMVectorZero()));
assert(!XMVector3IsInfinite(EyeDirection));
assert(!XMVector3Equal(UpDirection, XMVectorZero()));
assert(!XMVector3IsInfinite(UpDirection));
```

Comment: Why are you not using ``XMVector3Transform``? Unless your ``XMMATRIX`` includes projection transforms, you don't need to use ``XMVector3TransformCoord``.

Comment: Well i do not need the W parameter of the XMMATRIX so i though it would be best to grab only to coordinates (x,y,z). Also i have a seperate XMMATRIX to deal with projections,

Comment: ``XMVector3TransformCoord``  divides by the w component after transformation. You don't need to do that with affine transformations, which is why there's a distinct function from ``XMVector3Transform``

Comment: oh i did not know that. So what exactly does that W component do to my 3D vector?

Comment: Look up "Homogeneous Coordinates". The 4x4 matrix allows you to encode all affine transformations, but so does a 4x3 matrix where you implicitly treat the last row/column as [0 0 0 1]. The reason 4x4 matrices are the standard instead of 3x3 matrix + a translation is for non-affine transformations such as the projection. After such a non-affine projection, the resulting 4-vector does not actually have meaning in 3D space until you normalize by the w component.

Comment: So right now i am normalizing my Forward and Right vector (Z and X axis) and crossing them to calculate my Y axis. Would you recommend using TransformCoord or Transform?

Comment: Correct. Unless your matrix is a non-affine transformation, the extra divide is a waste of time because w is always 1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the line of code :

```
XMVECTOR position = XMVector3TransformCoord(cam->GetCharPos(), World);
```

With the way XMVECTOR and XMMATRIX work, it won't let you store the value of **XMVector3TransformCoord(cam->GetCharPos(), World)** directly into the **XMVECTOR position**.

To fix this i wrote:

```
cam->GetCharPos() = XMVector3TransformCoord(cam->GetCharPos(), World);
```

Since i m updating a default XMVECTOR ( Remember, cam->GetCharPos() was set to (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) ) from a XMMATRIX, i then copied it's content to my **position** XMVECTOR. This enables me to manipulate it without breaking the XNAlibrary